# ws-security and transport security

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, ws-security

I can not understand the following: WS-Security and https are presented as alternatives.
The problem though with https (as described) is when there intermediaries i.e. proxies are between client and server.
Then we can work arround and guarrantee point-to-point security e.g. between proxy and server but not end to end.
So we can have:

> Client <--(secure)--> Proxy
>   <--(secure)-->Server

But this is not equal to

```
Client <--(secure)--> Server
```

So why is not the end-to-end guaranteed? Could someone please give a specific example?
Also if in my network I do not have any proxies does this mean that https is ok?
And vice versa if I have proxies I MUST use WS-Security instead?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is not exactly correct. With HTTPS your communication is secure between client and server. Proxy doesn't know anything about the communication except one thing - the host you are communicating to. This is achieved by using HTTPS proxy (HTTP Connect command, see RFC 2616 for details). So there's no problem with HTTPS (I don't know where you've found the opposite).

Comment: @Eugene:Thank you replying.You can even look in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security#Alternative. It mentions this

Comment: @user384706 Wikipedia text talks about "if messages needed to go through an application level proxy server". HTTPS proxy is not an application-level proxy (unlike HTTP proxy) but transport level proxy: HTTPS proxy builds a tunnel between a client and a server (or another proxy) and then sends the data back and forth without looking inside.

Comment: @Eugene:I see, but in this case why was WS-Security needed/introduced?

Comment: I mean if the security of the underlying transport layer is adequate?

Comment: @user384706 WS-Security provides different security mechanisms and for different purpose. TLS is a transport layer security - it provides encryption services, but it's other security functions (authentication, non-repudiation) are limited. Also, TLS can not provide end-to-end security if your messages must be forwarded or load-balanced or in other way retransmitted to backend servers. In these cases WS-Security is the only method to hide message contents for intermediate hosts.

Comment: @Eugene:" TLS can not provide end-to-end security if your messages must be forwarded" you mean if the intermidery is not an HTTPS proxy?

Comment: @user384706 "if the messages must be forwarded" means no established transport channel between a client and a server. In this case message reaches the router (proxy, load balancer etc.) using one transport channel and then the message is routed to other destination using different transport channel. In this case there's more than one channel and end-to-end security can't be properly provided.