# Transport Security with WCF, IIS, along with client authentication.. is it possible or not?

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate, iis-7.5

I can find out few similar questions on SO regarding this, but I am quite unsure about the answer to this. I get more and more confused as I read through different posts on this. So asking this for my satisfaction.

I have a WCF Service hosted on IIS. and I have a client which connects to this service and invokes a method. I now try to use certificates to make use of transport security.

On the client side I have a config

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="testBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  proxyCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="testBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="client007"/>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

On the server side I have a configuration

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="testServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="testServiceBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Now, the scenario I want is, only the client which has its public key installed on the trusted people of the server can only access the service.

But in my case, whether I install a public key in the trusted people or not. I can access the service with any certificate I self create.

I checked the anonymous authentication was enabled, is it because of this?  When I disable anonymous access I get a error saying

> the http request is unauthorized with client authentication the authentication received from the server was basic realm

How do I make sure only that client whose public key is on the server can access the service?

Does this kind of validation not work with transport security? Please help me. thanks