# Why is Message Security and Transport Security needed?

Tags: wcf

Please see the XML below:

```
  <client>
      <endpoint address="https://hq-wk-is.lincspolice.local/WCFSSL/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReferenceInsecure.IService1" name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
```

Here is a basicHttpBinding over HTTP.  The channel is encrypted.

What is the point of Message Security and Transport Security, which are apparently not available for basicHTTPBinding? The binding above is encrypted over HTTPS (using SSL).  Therefore why is MessageSecurity and TransportSecurity needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673283/wcf-transport-vs-message

Comment: Is Transport Security simply HTTPS? Therefore if you have a http service reference and specify Transport Security in the web.config, then it will use HTTPS? Is that correct?